# using awk to divide columns when separated by a colon

Tags: awk, split, division

I have a file that has multiple columns that look like this:

> `12080:1016      108:9   84:23   2708:270        146:18  610:127 24:6    94:6    478:59  2816:279        108:29  16332:1534`

Basically, for each column, I want to divide the second number by the first (i.e. 1016/12080, etc).

I want to print the values of the divisions of each column
I know I can do this by splitting all of the rows individually by the ':' then dividing, but that seems like a lot of extra work. There has got to be an easier way to do it, but I'm stuck.

Any advice would be great. Thanks

Comment: Kindly do add your efforts in form of code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { v = $i;split($i,d,":"); printf d[2]/d[1] " ";   }} ' input.txt > out.txt
```

> input.txt

```
12080:1016      108:9   84:23   2708:270        146:18  610:127 24:6    94:6    478:59  2816:279        108:29  16332:1534
```

> out.txt

```
0.084106 0.0833333 0.27381 0.0997046 0.123288 0.208197 0.25 0.0638298 0.123431 0.0990767 0.268519 0.093926
```

Comment: `-F" "` is doing nothing useful since `" "` is already the default FS value. What you're doing will cram all output from all input lines onto a single output line, add a trailing `,`, and not provide the terminating newline required for the result to be a valid POSIX text file. I'm also not sure why you think the OP wants comma-separated output anyway.

Comment: my mistake , changed the script, removed the `-F " "`, thanks Ed, and change it to `d [2] / d [1]`, thanks user3439894 , thanks for the feedback